# Find empy lines in text file

Tags: racket

I've been learning racket for a few days and I'm puzzled with this task, I'm trying to find empty lines in a text file and select a random empty line to INSERT the text "calculation here", this is as far as I have gotten so far.

for example: myfile.txt has the contents:

```
line1

line2
line3

line4
```

after the script is run, myfile.txt should now look like:

```
line1
calculation here
line2
line3

line4
```

or:

```
line1

line2
line3
calculation here
line4
```

un-working code below:

```
#lang racket

(define (write-to-file host text) (
             with-output-to-file host (                 
             lambda () (
             write text))
             #:exists 'replace))

(define empty-lines '()) ;store line number of empty line (if any)

(define (file-lines text-file) 
                (file->lines text-file))

(define (add-to-list line-num)
  (set! empty-lines (cons line-num empty-lines)))

(let loop ((l (file-lines "myfile.txt")))
   (cond ((null? l) #f)
         (else
           (printf "~s\n" (first l)) ; just for debugging
           (cond ((equal? (first l) "") (add-to-list (first l)))(else #f))
           (loop (rest l)))))

;now i need to select a random line from the list of empty-lines.
;and write "calculations here" to that line
```

there's no problem with the read lines method i am using, the problem is detecting and selecting a random empty space to insert my text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file name, you can read it into a list of lines using [`file->lines`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffile..rkt%29._file-~3elines%29%29).  So for instance:

```
(for ([line (in-list (file->lines "some-file"))])
  (displayln (cond [(zero? (string-length line)) (make-random-line)]
                   [else line])))
```

Where `make-random-line` is some function you define to return a
random string, as you said you wanted to do.

The above reads the entire file into a list in memory. For larger files, it would be better to process things line by line. You can do this using the [`in-lines`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-lines%29%29) sequence:

```
(with-input-from-file "some-file"
  (thunk
   (for ([line (in-lines)])
     (displayln (cond [(zero? (string-length line)) (make-random-line)]
                      [else line])))))
```

---

## Update

Now that I understand your question:

```
#lang racket

(define lines (file->lines "some-file-name"))

(define empty-line-numbers (for/list ([line (in-list lines)]
                                      [n    (in-naturals)]
                                      #:when (zero? (string-length line)))
                             n))

(define random-line-number (list-ref empty-line-numbers
                                     (random (length empty-line-numbers))))

(for ([line (in-list lines)]
      [n    (in-naturals)])
  (displayln (cond [(= n random-line-number) "SOME NEW STRING"]
                   [else line])))
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i've never said I wanted to return any sort of random string, I said I need to place a string in to a random empty space within the said file. I will rephrase my question.

Comment: do you do freelance work? can you contact me if you do.. thanks for the reply. seems to be no section on freelancer.com for racket programmers :/

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (read-next-line-iter file)
       (let ((line (read-line file)))
         (unless (eof-object? line)
           (display line)
           (newline)
           (read-next-line-iter file))))
(call-with-input-file "foobar.txt" read-next-line-iter)
```

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line#Racket

this function can help you read a file line by line. 
check if the length is 0. and replace that line with the comment

Answer (score -1):

look for 2 concurrent \n in the file. I am pretty sure there is a way in racket to do that. store those indices in a list select a pair randomly and replace the second \n with "calculation here\n".

Comment: Not too familiar with racket but if i were to do that, this would be my logic

Comment: (define (read-next-line-iter file)
    (let ((line (read-line file)))
      (unless (eof-object? line)
        (display line)
        (newline)
        (read-next-line-iter file))))
(call-with-input-file "foobar.txt" read-next-line-iter)

Comment: reading of the file works fine, i get all the lines in the list and it iterates them. the problem is adding the index of the empty lines to the empty-list and selecting a random place within the file to insert the text